# Verilog register cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment

Tags: verilog

I want to use a module in a test bench like this:

```
reg [31:0] OutputVal;
reg [15:0] InputVal;
sign theSignExtender(InputVal,OutputVal);
```

When I compile, I get the error:

> error:  reg OutputVal; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous
>   assignment.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
reg [31:0] OutputVal;
```

to:

```
wire [31:0] OutputVal;
```